# How to make table head position sticky at the top?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a scrollable table, I used "Static table vertical scroll" example code on https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/tables/scroll/, it's working fine but I want the header to stay sticked to the top, or if there is any way to make the scroll only on the body not the whole table

```
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar" style="max-height: 444px;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($clients as $client)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $client->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->company_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->user->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->user->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->user->address }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
.my-custom-scrollbar {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
    display: block;
}
```

I tried this with no success

```
.table-wrapper-scroll-y thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.table-wrapper-scroll-y thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar" style="max-height: 444px;">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>jems</td>
                <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason this code is not working, it keeps scrolling and the header is not sticky at the top. I tried it before as I stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sticky header then set the position to **sticky**. This will help to have a fixed header on scroll.

```
<style>

th{
position: sticky;
top: 0;
background: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: for some reason this code is not working, it keeps scrolling and the header is not sticky at the top. I tried it before as I stated in the question.